# ggplot, add lines to create grid that will surround each bubble?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bubble plot that looks like this.

```
iris$group = c ( rep ( "A", 50), rep ( "C", 25), rep ( "D", 50) ,rep ( "E", 25) )

ggplot(iris,
       aes(x =  group, 
           y =  Species ,
           colour = Species ,
           size = Sepal.Width )) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

this will create a bubble plot however what I really want is to have each bubble encased in a box. I drew the lines in read in the below picture. Is this possible?  When I turn on the grid ,it usually just cuts into the circles.

[image]

Comment: Do you need a "flexible" solution, or could you just tack on `+ geom_hline(yintercept = seq(1.5, 2.5, 1)) + geom_vline(xintercept = seq(1.5, 3.5, 1))` to the end of your `theme()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have many groups, then @Jared offers an easy solution. However, if you are wanting a more flexible solution that would work for many more groups, then here is a slight adjustment that takes into account the number of groups along the x and y axes.

```
library(ggplot2)

iris$group = c ( rep ( "A", 50), rep ( "C", 25), rep ( "D", 50) ,rep ( "E", 25) )

ggplot(iris,
       aes(x =  group, 
           y =  Species ,
           colour = Species ,
           size = Sepal.Width )) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(1.5, (length(unique(iris$Species)) - 0.5), 1)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(1.5, (length(unique(iris$group)) - 0.5), 1))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Yes I do need a more flexible since some plots can have many different combinations.